# BigDecimal.Divide gives incorrect result

Tags: java, math, bigdecimal

I am getting incorrect result while performing the division using BigDecimal.
number1 = 221500.0
number2 = 12.0
Here is my code snippet:

```
BigDecimal d1 = new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(number1)).setScale(13, 4);
BigDecimal d2 = new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(number2)).setScale(13, 4);
return (d1.divide(d2, 13, 4 )).doubleValue();
```

18458.333333333332

if I performed the same calculation using the calculator it gives 
18458.333333333333333333333333333

Let me know any issues with handling the scale in BigDecimal. It will be helpful if someone let me know how to arrive the same result with calculator.

Comment: It is the correct result. Do you really need such a long result?

Comment: The *exact* same result? Does your calculator spit out just the right amount of 3s, or? In reality there's an infinite amount of 3s.

Comment: BigDecimal is working exactly how it should be, given that you wanted 13  values. If your purposes require "exact division results" say, for comparison purposes, please multiply by some pre-determined threshold value and compare as ints. In your case, `double` can't hold the value, so the rounding.

Comment: *"to arrive the same result with calculator"* request 27 digits of precision (not 13), and don't convert to `double`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You asked the `divide()` call for 13 digits of precision, and that is what it gave you.

You then convert that to `double` and notice that `double` cannot handle that precision.

```
BigDecimal d1 = new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(221500.0)).setScale(13, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
BigDecimal d2 = new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(12.0)).setScale(13, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
BigDecimal d3 = d1.divide(d2, 13, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
System.out.println("BigDecimal: " + d3);
System.out.println("as double : " + d3.doubleValue());
```

**OUTPUT**

```
BigDecimal: 18458.3333333333333
as double : 18458.333333333332
```

If you're going to throw away the extra precision gained by using `BigDecimal`, why not just do the math in `double`?

---

On a different note:
Don't do `new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(doubleValue))`.
Use `BigDecimal.valueOf(doubleValue)`.

Setting the scale of `d1` and `d2` seems rather meaningless.
Unless explicitly needed, round as late as possible, if at all.

Comment: What @Andreas is saying is, dont call .doubleValue() as doing so will convert your highly precise number into a not so precise double

Answer (score 3):

There are some things you shall do differently.

As you know already, BigDecimal is a great tool since:

- it can preserve decimal digits exactly, unlike any floating point representation such as **double** or **float**
- it can work with arbitrary big decimal numbers, unlike **int**, **double** and **float**

However to make it working, you shall keep a few things in mind:

- When setting a value to a BigDecimal, **always** use a String representation, since only the String representation will handle decimal precision. For example, new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(number1)) is a bad idea, if number is a double (can not handle precise decimals) then you'll covert the unprecise number to a BigDecimal.
- Do not limit the precision when creating a BigDecimal. Normally a BigDecimal will keep the precision of the input, i.e. new BigDecimal("3.234") will have 3 decimal digits.
- Do set the roudingMode after each division. Refer to the JavaDoc for the possible rouding modes, the HALF_EVEN is the best pick for usual use cases.
- Do set the decimal precision at division, since a division may cause endless number of decimals.

Consider this example:

```
public class BigDecimalTest {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final BigDecimal d1 = new BigDecimal("221500");
        final BigDecimal d2 = new BigDecimal("12");
        final BigDecimal result=d1.divide(d2,30,RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);
        System.out.println(result);
    }

}
```

which gives

> 18458.333333333333333333333333333333

with all the 30 decimals requested. Feel free to change 30 to 300 which gives

> 18458.333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333

*Much* better than the calculator, isn't it? :)